# Rails: has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have three models

poll

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options
end
```

option

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
  has_many :votes
end
```

vote

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :option
end
```

How can I get all the votes for all the options of the poll like

```
Poll.find(params[:id]).votes
```

Thanks

Comment: Try into Poll model: `has_many :votes, through: :options`

Comment: Look at the [`has_many` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for more infos about the `through` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a `has_many :through` assocation on Poll:

```
class Poll
  belongs_to :poll
  has_many :votes, through: :options
end
```

More information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to Poll model

`has_many :votes, through: :options`

Answer (score 1):

Add into your Poll model:

```
has_many :votes, through: :options
```

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model.